# Bootstrap Carousel rendering but not sliding. Left right icons also don't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap carousel renders properly, however, it does not auto slide and when I click on one of the arrows it scrolls the page down slightly but otherwise does nothing.  I have double checked to make sure an item is set as active and that the list items have proper data-target.

My image is fine as well so its not that in any way.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/5vh42ufs/4/

```
<div id="mainPics" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="img/ball.png" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/ball.png" alt="Chicago">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/ball.png" alt="New York">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainPics" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainPics" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the Bootstrap JavaScript CDN after you import jQuery. For Bootstrap 3.4.0, you can add the following: `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`.

Importing jQuery alone just gives you access to the jQuery library, which does nothing by itself. Bootstrap still has its own JavaScript file that contains all of the code for the animations. Because Bootstrap uses jQuery and not vanilla JS, make sure you import the CDN **after** you import jQuery, or it will not work.

```css
nav {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

body {
  background: url(../img/back.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

#content {
  background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 600px 600px;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #222;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: #080808;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

footer {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#mainPics {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#item {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail a>img,
.thumbnail>img {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HMICSL - Home</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/ball.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/universal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="mx-auto navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" id="deviceTypeNav">Home Page</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="teams.html">Teams</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">

    <h1>Welcome to HMICSL</h1>

    <div id="mainPics" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#mainPics" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" alt="Chania">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Aspen-PopulusTremuloides-2001-09-27.jpg/220px-Aspen-PopulusTremuloides-2001-09-27.jpg" alt="Chicago">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://learnphotoediting.org/wp-content/uploads/tree-picture-live-oak-trees-for-sale-fast-growing-trees.jpg" alt="New York">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mainPics" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mainPics" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A noob mistake but one nonetheless